# Set up isometric view in grease pencil?

Tags: 2d

Other than adding a background image, how do you add a ismoetric grid to blender?

Comment: Can you add a little detail-- maybe some picture examples-- of what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

At the top, enable the Guides and choose isometric. Choose the angle.

For make the guide visible go in overlays (at top rigth) and avtive the canvas, like the image below:

[image]

To change the size of these canvas, go on object data proprerties and go on "Viewport Display" (see in the image above at left).